# Scale HTML elements heights only

Tags: html, height, scale

I have a table with cell heights set to different fixed values. Now I want this table to scale on some action so that cell widths will remain intact, but heights will be scaled by the same factor.

Of course, I could loop through all cells using JavaScript and set heights to them, but I hope to discover some single magic number that will scale heights only.

Does this possibility exist?

Answer (score 0):

it is simple to make with jQuery

```
$('td').each(function(){
    $(this).css({height:$(this).height(),width:'auto'});
});
```

or maybe you just need to set width:auto in your css when it needs

Comment: I decided to include some JSON with original values for each cell as reference.